# ¿Cómo auto ejecutar un botón al iniciar la página?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Quiero cargar una tabla inicial. Probé creando dos tablas: una que recargue sola y otra con los *select*, pero tenia conflictos con el **DataTable**.

Se me ocurrió que el botón que toma los valores del *select* y los envia al **ajax**, se ejecute automaticamente la primera vez que se carga la página.

¿existe esa solución?

```javascript
//Corresponde al select descripcion
function listaTipoOperador(id_operador) {
  var id_operador = $('#slc_tipoOperador').val();
  var idtipo_Operador = $('#slc_tipoOperador').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "api/operadores/lista_tipo_operador",
    success: function(response) {
      let cadena = '<option value = "' + 0 + '"> TODOS: </option>'
      response.forEach(elemento => {
        elemento.idtipo_operador;
        elemento.descripcion;
        cadena += '<option value = "' + elemento.idtipo_operador + '">' + elemento.descripcion + '</option>';
      });
      $('#slc_tipoOperador').append(cadena);
      $('slc_tipoOperador').html();
    }
  });
}

//tabla recibe parametros del select para filtrar por descripcion
function tablaOperadores(idtipo_operador, estado) {
  var idtipo_Operador = $('#slc_tipoOperador').val();
  var estado = $('#slc_estado').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "api/operadores/tabla_operador/" + idtipo_operador + "/" + estado,
    success: function(response) {
      let thead = '<thead><tr class="info"><th style="width: 10%; padding: 0px; padding-left: 10px;">Id</th><th style="width: 50%; padding: 0px; padding-left: 10px;">Nombre</th><th style="width: 10%; padding: 0px; padding-left: 10px;">Tipo</th><th style="width: 10%; padding: 0px; padding-left: 10px;">Estado</th><th style="width: 20%; padding: 0px;">&nbsp;</th></tr></thead>';

      response.forEach(elemento => {
        thead += '<tr>' +
          '<td style="padding: 0px; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 5px; vertical-align: middle;">' + elemento.idoperador + '</td>' +
          '<td style="padding: 0px; font-size: 12px; vertical-align: middle;">' + elemento.nombre_apellido + '</td>' +
          '<td style="padding: 0px; font-size: 12px; vertical-align: middle;">' + elemento.tipo_operador + '</td>' +
          '<td style="padding: 0px; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 20px; vertical-align: middle;">' + (elemento.estado == 0 ? 'Inactivo' : 'Activo') + '</td>' +
          '<td style="height: 5px; padding: 4px;" align="center">' +
          '<a class="btn btn-xs bg-navy " style="margin:2px" id="ver" title="Ver Datos del Operador" onclick="cargarOperador ( ' + elemento.idoperador + ', `edit` ,' + elemento.id_usuario + ' );"><i class= "fa fa-eye "></i></a>' +
          '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" style="margin:2px" id="editar" title="Actualizar Datos del operador" onclick="cargarOperador( ' + elemento.idoperador + ', `this` ,' + elemento.id_usuario + ' );"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o "></i></a>' +
          '<a class="btn btn-xs bg-yellow" style="margin:2px" title="Cambiar Estado" onclick="cambiarEstado(' + elemento.idoperador + ',' + elemento.estado + ');"><i class="fa fa-exchange " ></i></a>' +
          '</td>' + '</tr>';
      });

      $('#listaOperadores').html(thead);
      $('#listaOperadores').DataTable();
    }
  });
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <form action="api/operadores/tabla_operador/" method="GET">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <select class="form-control" id="slc_tipoOperador" name="slc_tipoOperador">
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <select class="form-control" id="slc_estado" name="slc_estado">
        <option value="estado">Estado</option>
        <option value="1">Activos</option>
        <option value="0">Inactivos</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" title="registrar" style="font-size: 12px; width: 50%%; display: block;" id="Buscar Operador" onClick="tablaOperadores($('#slc_tipoOperador').val()); $('#listaOperadores').DataTable().destroy()"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Buscar</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

no es todo el html , es decir me funciona todo correcto, solo que me gustaria que se ejecute la primera vez automaticamente, para no tener que crear dos tablas.

Comment: Cuando tiene que estar aqui, en 24 horas.

Comment: Los id= no llevan espacios, corrige eso primero: `id="Buscar Operador"`, sino no se podrá encontrar correctamente con jquery

Comment: No necesariamente tienes que autoclickear un botón, puedes hacer la petición Ajax al terminar cargar la página y en automático generar la tabla.

Comment: @emanuel: Antes pensé que te habia funcionado mi solución... ¿no es así?  ¿que ha ocurrido pues?  ¿algun error inesperado?

Comment: siii ,se veia bien pero me funciono regular, que paso? como estoy usando un DataTable el boton no deja de clickarse y no me deja usar los imput de busqueda que ya carga el DataTable, tampoco puedo utilizar los botones de paginacion . Entonces empecé a buscar una alternativa diferente.

Comment: @emanuel No entiendo eso de "el boton no deja de clickarse"... en principio esa linea solo se ejecuta una sola vez si la pones en el sitio correcto, que seria, por ejemplo, al inicio del script que estes usando, o si usas `$(document).ready(function () { ` entonces allí dentro, que es cuando termina de cargar el DOM.

Comment: Si , tenias razon , por otro lado estaba mal la consulta del modelo, agregue unos if(isset para cada parametro, entonces carga la tabla al iniciar aunque no se envíen parámetros .  De todos modos gracias por enseñarme un nuevo metodo de jquery

Comment: @emanuel perfecto, ya me extrañaba a mi :-)  Me alegro que te haya servido y/o hayas aprendido este método para lanzar eventos, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con el método [trigger()](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) (disparador) de jquery.

Suponiendo que el id= del boton es `id="BuscarOperador"` prueba con esto fuera de las funciones, es decir, cuando se carga el DOM:

```
$('#BuscarOperador').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

oye en vez de ejecutar un botón al iniciar la página ya intentaste ejecutar una función al cargar una página?
tipo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {  función aqui }
</script>
```

Comment: es buena alternativa, lo que pasa es que al no recibir los parametros el ajax , solo me devuelve la funcion con tabla vacia. Es decir, funciona, pero no recibe datos hasta que no se haga el submit del boton. Y con la aternativa del trigger  no deja de apretarse el boton, tanto es asi que no se puede utilziar ningun boton